# how to give a if else here

Tags: php, if-statement

i want to include a else statement after the completion of the block after the second if for category equal to helathcare ....now i want another else for finance but i am not getting where excatly to place that else 
i have a confusion on where to keep the else for finance and 2 more categories 
now whenever i try to place the one else at the last goes unrecable to its if statement i donno its very confusing as to where to place 2 more else if statments for 2 more categories

```
<?php
global $row2;
if(isset($_POST['category']))
{
            if($_POST['category']== 'Healthcare')
            {

            $query = "select *from event where category = 'Healthcare';";
            $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query)or die(mysqli_error($conn));
             while($row2= mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
             {
            ?>
    <div class="events events-full event-list">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-8"> 
            <!--Blog Post Start-->
            <div class="blog-post">
              <div class="post-thumb">
                <div class="link-wrap"> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a> </div>
                <img src="images/gallery/<?php echo $row2['event_image']?>" alt='user'></div>
              <div class="event-text">
                <div class="event-counter"></div>
                <h4> <a href="#"><?php echo($row2['title']); ?></a> </h4>
                <p><?php echo($row2['descrption']); ?></p>
                <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"><?php echo($row2['location']); ?></span></p>
                <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-grain"><?php echo($row2['organizer']); ?></span></p>
                <a class="nd" href="">
                  <form action="eventdetail.php" method="post">

<input type='hidden' value="<?php echo $row2['id']; ?>" name='id'/>


<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="detail" value=”detail”>Event Detail</button>
            </div>
                </a> </div>
            </div>
          </form>

            <!--Blog Post End-->
  <?php } 








}




}

        else
        {


              global $row2;
            $query = "select *from event;"  ;
            $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query)or die(mysqli_error($conn));
             while($row2= mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
             {
            ?>
    <div class="events events-full event-list">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-8"> 
            <!--Blog Post Start-->
            <div class="blog-post">
              <div class="post-thumb">
                <div class="link-wrap"> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a> </div>
                <img src="images/gallery/<?php echo $row2['event_image']?>" alt='user'></div>
              <div class="event-text">
                <div class="event-counter"></div>
                <h4> <a href="#"><?php echo($row2['title']); ?></a> </h4>
                <p><?php echo($row2['descrption']); ?></p>
                <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"><?php echo($row2['location']); ?></span></p>
                <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-grain"><?php echo($row2['organizer']); ?></span></p>
                <a class="nd" href="">
                  <form action="eventdetail.php" method="post">

<input type='hidden' value="<?php echo $row2['id']; ?>" name='id'/>


<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="detail" value=”detail”>Event Detail</button>
            </div>
                </a> </div>
            </div>
          </form>

            <!--Blog Post End-->
            <?php  } } ?>

       ?>
```

Comment: First, fix your code. Your closing tags aren't closed, or are closed in the right places. Then use some sensible formatting, and you should be able to see what is supposed to go where.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put multiple `else` blocks along with the `if` block. However, you can use multiple(as many as you want) `elseif/else if` blocks along with the `if` block, like this:

```
if($_POST['category'] == 'Healthcare'){
    ...
}elseif($_POST['category'] == 'Finance'){
    ...
}elseif($_POST['category'] == '...'){
    ...
}else{
    ...
}
```

Here's the reference: **http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php**

Answer (score 0):

Part of your problem seems to be poor formatting. If you lined up your open and close tags for your if statements I think you would be able to see this better. Having said that, you can add any elseif/if clauses for the category if where I marked below:

```
<!--Blog Post End-->
<?php 
} // closes while loop

} else{ } // closes healthcare if, add extra else here

} // closes POST if

else
{
```